start cron as subprocess of my c++ application
I want to trigger some processes within my app using the cron syntax for scheduling
My thought was to spawn a seperate cron deamon as a subprocess of my app, making it visible for sysadmins (like for example tar exposes it's compression subprocess xz, gz and other in top) and then advise cron to issue RESTful curl calls to myself (as my app is running as a server already anyway). This approach would have the benefit that I don't have to do the parsing of the cron syntax and use the already existing RESTful interface to do my operations, increasing the transparency of operations.
My question though is how do I launch a seperate cron subprocess and assign a seperate crontab file to it to use? Also I want to update the crontab used by cron after the subprocess dispatch. So there should be consistent communication between my app and the cron subprocess. Is this possible?
Note: Our productive servers run debian and redhat.

Is this just about starting a process or is this problem specific to cron ? Why can't you just start it as you normally would start any other application ? The question and tags don't specify the exact problem.

@AhmedAEK starting processes in general I guess. But it seems to be not straightforward at all and differ on the kind of task. I would intuitively have used system() but people advise against it (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699974/best-way-to-run-child-process-in-c-if-you-want-to-get-output-of-the-called-com), even on linux. So what should I use instead? I guess if I could somehow also get cron output for error checking this would be nice.

Why not using the default cron ?

@Philippe Default cron is already spamming a lot of services and I don't want to pollute the system crontab. Or if you mean by default cron, I want to start the system cron yes, but with my own crontab file and as an additional deamon.
